# make an ID in a mysql table auto_increment (after the fact)

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I acquired a database from another developer.  He didn't use auto_incrementers on any tables.  They all have primary key ID's, but he did all the incrementing manually, in code.

Can I turn those into Auto_incrementers now?

---

Wow, very nice, thanks a ton. It worked without a hitch on one of my tables. But a second table, i'm getting this error...Error on rename of '.\DBNAME#sql-6c8_62259c' to '.\DBNAME\dealer_master_events'

Answer (score 113, accepted):

For example, here's a table that has a primary key but is not `AUTO_INCREMENT`:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
mysql> INSERT INTO foo VALUES (1), (2), (5);
```

You can `MODIFY` the column to redefine it with the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Verify this has taken effect:

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE foo;
```

Outputs:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Note that you have modified the column definition in place, without requiring creating a second column and dropping the original column.  The `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is unaffected, and you don't need to mention in in the `ALTER TABLE` statement.

Next you can test that an insert generates a new value:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO foo () VALUES (); -- yes this is legal syntax
mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Outputs:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 | 
|  2 | 
|  5 | 
|  6 | 
+----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I tested this on MySQL 5.0.51 on Mac OS X.

I also tested with `ENGINE=InnoDB` and a dependent table.  Modifying the `id` column definition does not interrupt referential integrity.

---

To respond to the error 150 you mentioned in your comment, it's probably a conflict with the foreign key constraints.  My apologies, after I tested it I thought it would work.  Here are a couple of links that may help to diagnose the problem:

- [What does mysql error 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './foo' (errorno: 150) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-mean)
- http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2008/03/mysql_errno_150.html

Comment: Wow, very nice, thanks a ton.  It worked without a hitch on one of my tables.  But a second table, i'm getting this error...Error on rename of '.\DBNAME\#sql-6c8_62259c' to '.\DBNAME\dealer_master_events' (errno: 150)

Comment: if the primary key is already acting as a foreign key somewhere else, you will need to disable foreign-key checks before you run the alter table query.
`set foreign_key_checks = 0;
ALTER TABLE buyer MODIFY COLUMN _id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
set foreign_key_checks = 1;`

Comment: @mugumedavid, that's not correct. I just tried it. You can change the parent table and make its primary key auto_increment even if there are dependent tables referencing it. Likewise in the other direction, if you want to add auto_increment to a PK that is also an FK (not sure why you'd do that).

Comment: @billkarwin i honestly failed to in my case, which led me to this page and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90162/adding-autoincrement-to-id-already-part-of-foreign-key It could be my db version or myIsam vs Innodb

Answer (score 6):

None of the above worked for my table. I have a table with an unsigned integer as the primary key with values ranging from 0 to 31543. Currently there are over 19 thousand records. I had to modify the column to `AUTO_INCREMENT` (`MODIFY COLUMN`'id'`INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`) and set the seed(`AUTO_INCREMENT = 31544`) in the same statement.

```
ALTER TABLE `'TableName'` MODIFY COLUMN `'id'` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT = 31544;
```

Comment: This is crucial, and was the only thing that worked for me (MySQL 5.6/OSX). If you already  have a primary key that is *not* autoincrement and you alter it to be  autoincrement, you must (at least in my configuration, which is 100% defaults) do them in the same statement, otherwise INSERTs that do not supply the ID will fail with e.g. `ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'id' doesn't have a default value`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that you don't need to re-increment the existing data so, why can't you just run a simple ALTER TABLE command to change the PK's attributes?

Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE `content` CHANGE `id` `id` SMALLINT( 5 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

I've tested this code on my own MySQL database and it works but I have not tried it with any meaningful number of records. Once you've altered the row then you need to reset the increment to a number guaranteed not to interfere with any other records.

```
ALTER TABLE `content` auto_increment = MAX(`id`) + 1
```

Again, untested but I believe it will work.

Comment: I don't think the second `ALTER` is needed.  And I think that it will fail, since the syntax calls for a "value", not an "expression".

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (i wanted to make id primary and  set auto increment)

ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `id` `id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` MODIFY COLUMN `bar_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `foo` CHANGE `bar_id` `bar_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

But none of these will work if your `bar_id` is a foreign key in another table: you'll be getting

```
an error 1068: Multiple primary key defined
```

To solve this, temporary disable foreign key constraint checks by

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

and after running the statements above, enable them back again.

```
set foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easy. Just run a data-definition query to update the tables, adding an AUTO_INCREMENT column.

If you have an existing database, be careful to preserve any foreign-key relationships that might already be there on the "artificially created" primary keys.

Answer (score -2):

As long as you have unique integers (or some unique value) in the current PK, you could create a new table, and insert into it with IDENTITY INSERT ON. Then drop the old table, and rename the new table.

Don't forget to recreate any indexes.

Comment: That option is specific to Microsoft SQL Server and it has no relevance to MySQL.