# MySQL Removing Some Foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints, mysql-error-1025

I have a table whose primary key is used in several other tables and has several foreign keys to other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE location (
   locationID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
   ...
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE assignment (
   assignmentID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   locationID INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY locationIDX (locationID) REFERENCES location (locationID)
   ...
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE assignmentStuff (
   ...
   assignmentID INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY assignmentIDX (assignmentID) REFERENCES assignment (assignmentID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to drop one of the foreign key columns (ie locationIDX) it gives me an error.

> "ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename"

How can I drop the column in the assignment table above without getting this error?

Answer (score 526, accepted):

As explained [here](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14347), seems the *foreign key* constraint has to be dropped by **constraint name** and not the *index* name.

The syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE footable DROP FOREIGN KEY fooconstraint;
```

Comment: This was my problem. I feel kind of dumb now. If anyone else has this problem, you can find the Foreign Key Constraint names by using the SHOW CREATE TABLE function.

Comment: Tip: use `SHOW CREATE TABLE footable;` to see what the name of the constraint is. It isn't the name of the column per-se. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can use this to find foreign key constraints: SELECT *
FROM information_schema.table_constraints
WHERE constraint_schema = '<your db name>'
AND constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'

Answer (score 21):

The foreign keys are there to ensure data integrity, so you can't drop a column as long as it's part of a foreign key.  You need to drop the key first.

I would think the following query would do it:

```
ALTER TABLE assignmentStuff DROP FOREIGN KEY assignmentIDX;
```

Answer (score 19):

As everyone said above, you can easily delete a FK. However, I just noticed that it can be necessary to drop the KEY itself at some point. If you have any error message to create another index like the last one, I mean with the same name, it would be useful dropping everything related to that index.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_with_fk
  drop FOREIGN KEY name_of_your_fk_from_show_create_table_command_result,
  drop KEY the_same_name_as_above
```

Comment: _'the_same_name_as_above'_ does not works. See the @norodin answer, it worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

Check what's the CONSTRAINT name and the FOREIGN KEY name:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
```

Remove both the CONSTRAINT name and the FOREIGN KEY name:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  DROP FOREIGN KEY the_name_after_CONSTRAINT,
  DROP KEY the_name_after_FOREIGN_KEY;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Hey I followed some sequence above, 
and found some solution.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE footable;
```

You will get FK Constrain Name like

```
ProjectsInfo_ibfk_1
```

Now you need to remove this constraints. by alter table commantd

```
alter table ProjectsInfo drop foreign key ProjectsInfo_ibfk_1;
```

Then drop the table column,

```
alter table ProjectsInfo drop column clientId;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to drop foreign key constraint, it will work.
ALTER TABLE `location`.`location_id` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `location_ibfk_1`;

Answer (score 1):

You usually get this error if your tables use the InnoDB engine. In that case you would have to drop the foreign key, and then do the alter table and drop the column.

But the tricky part is that you can't drop the foreign key using the column name, but instead you would have to find the name used to index it. To find that, issue the following select:

SHOW CREATE TABLE region;
This should show you a row ,at left upper corner click the +option ,the click the full text raio button then click the go .there you will get the name of the index, something like this:

CONSTRAINT region_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (country_id) REFERENCES  country (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
Now simply issue an:

alter table region drop foreign key  region_ibfk_1;

or

more simply just type:-
alter table TableName drop foreign key  **TableName_ibfk_1**;

remember the only thing is to add        **_ibfk_1**     after your tablename to make like this:-    TableName**_ibfk_1**

Answer (score 1):

first need to get actual constrain name by this query

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
```

This query will result constrain name of the foreign key, now below query will drop it.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME DROP FOREIGN KEY COLUMN_NAME_ibfk_1
```

last number in above constrain name depends how many foreign keys you have in table

Answer (score 0):

You can not drop the foreign key column because it is being referenced from the table `assignmentStuff`. So you should first drop the foreign key constraint `assignmentStuff.assignmentIDX`.

A similar question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-mean). Check also [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/22/mysqls-error-1025-explained/) for more info.

Comment: So, because assignmentStuff references assignment's primary key, I cannot drop assignment's locationID column? 

This seems kind of counter intuitive.

Comment: It seems I've switched some column names so my answer doesn't really make sense. Sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alter table Documents drop
  FK__Documents__Custo__2A4B4B5E
```

Answer (score 0):

step1: `show create table vendor_locations;`

step2: `ALTER TABLE vendor_locations drop foreign key vendor_locations_ibfk_1;`

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a unique constraint on a field which is also a foreign key. My purpose is to drop the entire table but the `migrate` give me `ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints`.

So I used different pieces of yours answers for make that work :

> ALTER TABLE `tablename`
> DROP INDEX `tablename_fieldname_fk_blabla_id`,
> DROP FOREIGN KEY `tablename_fieldname_fk_blabla_id`;

Executing this, and drop the `options={'unique_together': {(field1, field2)},}` line into the 0001_initial (I don't keep the migrations history, but if you do, I guess you have to edit this option or the AlterUniqueTogether into 0002 or further migrations) just before to run again `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

I got the `tablename_fieldname_fk_blabla_id` key_name with the given above command :

> SHOW INDEX FROM tablename;

Finally, no more constraint on my table, the migrate deleted the table !