# Show all the constraints of all tables in database

Tags: mysql, constraints

How do I get a list of all constraints from MySQL database?

Comment: There is more than one type of constraint in MySQL. Which do you mean? Can you give an example of the sort of thing you are looking for?

Answer (score 174):

Use the [`information_schema.table_constraints`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/table-constraints-table.html) table to get the names of the constraints defined on each table:

```
select *
from information_schema.table_constraints
where constraint_schema = 'YOUR_DB'
```

Use the [`information_schema.key_column_usage`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/key-column-usage-table.html) table to get the fields in each one of those constraints:

```
select *
from information_schema.key_column_usage
where constraint_schema = 'YOUR_DB'
```

If instead you are talking about foreign key constraints, use [`information_schema.referential_constraints`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/referential-constraints-table.html):

```
select *
from information_schema.referential_constraints
where constraint_schema = 'YOUR_DB'
```

Comment: This list will only include UNIQUE, PRIMARY KEY, or FOREIGN KEY constraints.  CHECK is possible, but isn't enforced.  DEFAULT constraints will not be visible using this query.

Comment: MySQL does not store CHECK constraints.  If you try to define one, it parses and silently discards it.

Comment: The DEFAULT value doesn't count as a constraint.  It's stored in `information_schema.columns.column_default`.

Answer (score 25):

Great answer by @Senseful.

I am presenting modified query for those who are only looking for list of constraint names (and not other details/columns):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(constraint_name) 
FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
WHERE constraint_schema = 'YOUR_DB' 
ORDER BY constraint_name ASC;
```

Comment: if you need to delete one once you find it, see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/838412/2401804

Answer (score 18):

This really helps if you want to see primary and foreign key constraints as well as rules around those constraints such as ON_UPDATE and ON_DELETE and the column and foreign column names all together:

```
SELECT tc.constraint_schema,tc.constraint_name,tc.table_name,tc.constraint_type,kcu.table_name,kcu.column_name,kcu.referenced_table_name,kcu.referenced_column_name,rc.update_rule,rc.delete_rule

FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc

inner JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
ON tc.constraint_catalog = kcu.constraint_catalog
AND tc.constraint_schema = kcu.constraint_schema
AND tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
AND tc.table_name = kcu.table_name

LEFT JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints rc
ON tc.constraint_catalog = rc.constraint_catalog
AND tc.constraint_schema = rc.constraint_schema
AND tc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name
AND tc.table_name = rc.table_name

WHERE tc.constraint_schema = 'my_db_name'
```

You may even want to add in some further information about those columns, simply add this into the SQL (and select the columns you want):

```
LEFT JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS c
ON kcu.constraint_schema = c.table_schema
AND kcu.table_name = c.table_name
AND kcu.column_name = c.column_name
```

Comment: There is both time the "table_name" but else it's perfect

Answer (score 1):

To see the related constraints for your table just use:

```
select * from information_schema.table_constraints where CONSTRAINT_NAME like 'YOUR_TABLE%';
```

Comment: This is actual answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

SELECT * FROM USER_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = "tabnam";

Comment: This is in Oracle, not MySQL, as far as I know.