# Get mysql to show table with references

Tags: mysql

the command `show create table myTable` shows the foreign keys but without the parent table. Is there a way to also view the parent tables?

What I get is this:

```
KEY `FK_friend_id` (`friend_id`)
```

What I want to see is this (or something that shows `customer`):

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_friend_id` FOREIGN KEY (friend_id) REFERENCES customer (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: no, but you can `show create table name_of_parent_table` yourself.

Comment: was your foreign key set to the fields ?

Comment: @kasavbere ,which Engine  are you using ?

Comment: Check this answer, this should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3024995/1268844

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding i could say that ,

`Foreign Key` have not created for it,

For Creating `Foreign key` Constraint ,Use `Innodb Engine` ,bcz if you have used `MYISAM Engine` it may fail to create the Foreign Keys ,  just we could see the primary keys alone as you mentioned

Correct me if 'm wrong ,

Comment: The tables are created by hibernate. And you are right, it's using `MyISAM`. Many thanks (up vote). Only problem, I am new to hibernate and don't know how to set the engine.

Comment: Thats fine ..Welcome @Kasavbere