# MySQL update a constraint unique

Tags: mysql, indexing, key, constraints, unique

i have a Problem. I created a table in MySQL with a Primary key and two foreign keys.
The two foreign keys C and R have to be unique as pair. For the Moment this works.

But then i decided adding a 3rd key CR_New because of a new System feature. Now a combination of C_ID, R_ID and CR_New has to be unique. But it doesn´t work, even with the Solutions i already found in the Internet. I get error 1553 when dropping the foreign keys. A combination of the keys C_ID and R_ID is allowed multiple times if CR_New is different.

```
CREATE TABLE CR(
CR_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
CR_Grade TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
C_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
R_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(CR_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(C_ID) REFERENCES C(C_ID),
FOREIGN KEY(R_ID) REFERENCES R(R_ID),
CONSTRAINT UNIQUE(R_ID, C_ID));

ALTER TABLE CR ADD COLUMN CR_New INT;
UPDATE CR SET CR_New = 42;

ALTER TABLE CR ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (C_ID, R_ID, CR_New);

ALTER TABLE CR DROP FOREIGN KEY C_ID;
ALTER TABLE CR DROP FOREIGN KEY R_ID;
ALTER TABLE CR DROP INDEX C_ID;
ALTER TABLE CR DROP INDEX R_ID;
```

If you want to know which use i want to have from it: Just imagine C is a Student, R a subject and CR_New the year, and CR_Grade the grade of the Student. Now it is just possible to save the grade for a subject, but i want to extend it for saving the grade for a subject for each year.

BTW thats not the original use but works the same way.

Comment: You need drop old unique constraint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487691/dropping-unique-constraint-from-mysql-table

Comment: how do i find out the Name of the old unique constraint? I know there id SHOW INDEX FROM but how should this be named?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024981/list-of-constraints-from-mysql-database

Comment: is it possible that it is just names like the first column from the constraint?

Comment: just checked, "show index" shows unique constrints on table

Comment: DROP Constraint_Name FROM CR still gives me error 1553

Comment: try to use `alter table TableName drop index IndexName`

Comment: thats what i tried atthe first time to remove the foreign keys but it also gives me error 1553 :-( it always says it it used by foreign key constraints, i already tried to drop them because in another question i read that the foreign keys have to be dropped first

Comment: this keys in other tables referencing to this table. or you delete the wrong index

Comment: Start over.  Use _real_ column names.  Get rid of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` and replace the `PRIMARY KEY` with whatever combination of columns is `UNIQUE`. Don't have any `FOREIGN KEYs`.  Then it may be easier to discuss what `FOREIGN KEYs` can/should be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved the Problem by creating new tables. After filling them with my data I renamed them and now it works. Should work fine for a test-database :-)