# How to drop a foreign key from a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, foreign-keys, relation

I accidentally made a foreign key with a primary within a table. I would like to delete the Index but if I try, it gives me: "Cannot drop index "admin_id" needed in a foreign key constraint."

How can I delete the relation?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "a foreign key with a primary" even means...?

Comment: Uh yeah maybe I wrote it bad. I meant that I made the relation with the same table's primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the the [FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) first - this relational constraint is established from the *foreign* table. Dropping a FK *constraint* does not drop or alter any column!

> ALTER TABLE foreign_table DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_constraint_name

Once there are no more constraints the KEY (e.g. INDEX, PK) status or entire column can be removed.

> ALTER TABLE primary_table DROP referenced_column_name

The same rules apply if the "foreign table" is the "same table".

---

See also:

- [How do I see all foreign keys to a table or column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column)
- [MySQL Removing Some Foreign keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838354/mysql-removing-some-foreign-keys)

Comment: I don't really understand this. I've tried to drop the admin_id coloumn but that gave the same message. And the PK is in the same table the connection is with.

Comment: @cyrfandli No column is dropped or altered when dropping the FK *constraint*. As such, the above violation will not occur.