# How can I drop this Foreign Key Column?

Tags: mysql

I have looked at some of the other questions similar to this one but have not had any luck. I am trying to delete the whole foreign key column from the blogs table. It is linked to a primary key in my students table as well.

```
Create table students
(
studentid integer primary key NOT NULL,
ulid varchar(20) NOT NULL,
password varchar(20) NOT NULL,
email varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

Create table blogs
(
blogid integer primary key NOT NULL,
blogdate date NOT NULL,
title varchar(50) NOT NULL,
description varchar(8000) NOT NULL,
category varchar (50) NOT NULL,
studentid integer NOT NULL,
foreign key (studentid) references students (studentid)
)
```

I tried this and it didn't work

```
alter table blogs drop column studentid

alter table blogs drop constraint studentid

alter table blogs drop foreign key studentid
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Removing Some Foreign keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838354/mysql-removing-some-foreign-keys). Basically, you need the actual constraint _name_, not which column it affects

Comment: But I do not know the constraint name...

Comment: The linked duplicate tells you how to find the constraint name.

Comment: @Tator if in your table only one foreign key is there then it will be normally like tablename_ibfk_1. for you it will be blogs_ibfk_1

Answer (score 0):

try this sql :

```
alter table blogs drop foreign key keyconstraint   // for you it will be `blogs_ibfk_1` i think
```

if you have any problem in droping the foreign constraind use:

```
show create table blogs
```

here you can see the created foreign key constraint name. then use it in sql

Comment: @Tator use the show sql which i have posted to know constraint name.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '//table name' at line 1

Comment: when I do that it shows CREATE TABLE `blogs` (
  `blogid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blogdate` date NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(8000) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `studentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`blogid`),
  KEY `studentid` (`studentid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: if your problem is solved then you can accept the answer and close this topic.