# mySQL Deleteing Foreign Key

Tags: mysql

I have a database, I used these commands :

```
CREATE TABLE APPOINTMENT (app_id INT(5) NOT NULL, app_doctor INT(5) NOT NULL, app_date DATE, PRIMARY KEY (app_id));

CREATE TABLE APPPATIENTS (patient_ssn INT(10) NOT NULL, patient_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, sex CHAR(1) NOT NULL, appointment_id INT(5), PRIMARY KEY (patient_ssn), UNIQUE (appointment_id));

ALTER TABLE APPPATIENTS ADD FOREIGN KEY (appointment_id) REFERENCES APPOINTMENT(app_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Now, I want to delete foreign key appointment_id in appPatients table :

```
ALTER TABLE apppatients DROP FOREIGN KEY appointment_id;
```

But I got an error :

```
Can't drop 'appointment_id'; check that column/key exists.
```

It is there! How can it give that error? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do this - 'SHOW KEYS IN apppatients' and watch result - may be you delete this foreign key in the past.

Comment: @degr I did what you said but my foreign key is still there.

Comment: is this foreign key have name 'appointment_id'?

Comment: and this one - alter table apppatients drop constraint appointment_id

Comment: @degr foreign key name is appointment_id, and I tried other command you said but I got a syntax error.

Comment: lol, I don't know. You query look good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838354/mysql-removing-some-foreign-keys

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a database with your code and I notice the foreign key name appears different from appointment_id: reading with more attention the command definition, I notice that when you write

```
ADD FOREIGN KEY (appointment_id)
```

you are only saying the column on which the constraint will be created, not its name.
You can read the specifications here:
[SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint on ALTER TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)

So, if you want to specify the name of the key, you have to write, for example:

```
alter table APPPATIENTS 
ADD CONSTRAINT appointment_key 
FOREIGN KEY (appointment_id) 
REFERENCES appointment(app_id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

And so you know the name of the foreign key you created (appointment_key in this case).
If you want to know the foreign key name generated by mysql you can use the command

```
show create table APPPATIENTS;
```

that shows the complete table definition.