# change primary key type without dropping foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a database with more than 70 tables, I used a software to copy all data and tables from oracle sql developer to mysql, all done successfully. 
I created all indexes and foreign keys, now I noticed that the software put the primarykeys (number in oracle) as double(22,0) in mysql, i want to change all the primarykeys and foreignkeys to INT without dropping my foreign keys, is there any solution ?

Comment: Start all over. (I hope you have a script you can edit.)

Comment: I'm talking about more than 70 tables, It's hard enough to repeat all the indexes and foreign keys

Comment: The next time you do something like this, have a script for the whole migration. Then you can easily repeat it if anything goes wrong.

Comment: this was for a guy that wasn't even changing datatypes on like 2 tables or 3: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39356872