# removing the foreign key from the tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to learn working with SQL and I am coding in mysql workbench and I can't understand why the code in below doesn't work. It says it has a syntax error but I don't know where.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_ONE DROP FOREIGN KEY
```

Comment: You have to specify which fk you want to drop. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838354/mysql-removing-some-foreign-keys

Comment: On a side note you may want to look at [How do i see all foreign keys on a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column) if you're unsure of what foreign keys are on your specified table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this-

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_ONE DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_Name
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to type the name of the specific foreign key to drop.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY id_name_fk;
```