# MySQL - Unable to create column

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1025

I am using MySQL 5.1. When i am trying to add new column, it throws error like this,

Database name is "ebill".

```
Error Code : 1025
Error on rename of '.\ebill\#sql-98_477' to '.\ebill\user' (errno: 150)
(0 ms taken)
```

This is my sql query:

```
alter table `ebill`.`user` add column `User_Password` varchar(25) NULL
```

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for an answer: [What does mysql error 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './foo' (errorno: 150) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-mea).