# MySql InnoDB ALTER TABLE errors

Tags: mysql, innodb, alter-table

My issue is similar to this question:

[ALTER TABLE error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920946/alter-table-error)

My message is:

```
#1025 - Error on rename of './balance/#A' to './balance/#B' (errno: -1)
```

Anytime I want to alter the table I get a cryptic message that it can't be done (like the above question).

All the research I've done points to an issue with foreign keys referencing the table in question. My table has no foreign keys and is quite simple, just a unique primary key.

MySQL documentation for this issue is spartan and does not give any details. I've had an issue in the past with permissions, and I couldn't even see the contents of innoDB tables, but I resolved that. I wonder if this could be some sort of permission issue. Using MySQL 5.5.15-log.

**This issue was resolved**. In my case it had to with with having forced recovery for my innodb tables enabled. I found it by looking in my log. When forced recovery is on, apparently no changes are allowed to the DB.

Now, the fact that it generated a foreign key error in my InnoDB engine log with no FKs is another issue.....I posted it as a bug to MySQL.

Comment: Can you send the exact command you're trying to execute?

Comment: RENAME TABLE `x`.`y` TO `x`.`z` ;

MySQL said: Documentation
    #1025 - Error on rename of './x/y' to './x/z' (errno: -1)

Comment: "MySQL documentation for this issue is **spartan** and does not give any details" - I agree, THIS IS MADNESS!!!!