# Error renaming a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, alter-table, mysql-error-1025

How do I rename a column in table `xyz`? The columns are:

```
Manufacurerid, name, status, AI, PK, int
```

I want to rename to `manufacturerid`

I tried using PHPMyAdmin panel, but I get this error:

```
MySQL said: Documentation
#1025 - Error on rename of '.\shopping\#sql-c98_26' to '.\shopping\tblmanufacturer' (errno: 150)
```

Comment: You're trying to change a table that has a foreign key reference in it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming foreign-key columns in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014498/renaming-foreign-key-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 753, accepted):

Lone Ranger is very close... in fact, you also need to specify the datatype of the renamed column. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE `xyz` CHANGE `manufacurerid` `manufacturerid` INT;
```

Remember  :

- Replace INT with whatever your column data type is (REQUIRED)
- Tilde/ Backtick (`) is optional

Comment: I think the column contains a foreign key to getting the error of the answer so you have to Drop foreign key, alter table, and add foreign key (it's better to backup first) and u can alter it by only changing the name in right click on the table - alter table

Comment: Keep in mind that in this solution you lose all other column definitions such as nullability, default value, etc. (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553130/rename-a-column-in-mysql-table-without-having-to-repeat-its-type-definition).

Comment: So basically, instead of `MODIFY column <TYPE>` (for redefining a column), it's `CHANGE column new_column <TYPE>`?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` can help you figure out current column definition

Comment: @Dejan thanks and this is really annoying, why require a type when you can't specify any other modifiers? Either require a type + modifiers or don't require it at all.

Comment: @JMac It appears that at lest since MySQL 5.1 all modifiers are supported, the type is just the only one that is required, and it is always required (like when you create a table).

Answer (score 44):

The standard MySQL rename statement is:

```sql
ALTER [ONLINE | OFFLINE] [IGNORE] TABLE tbl_name 
CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition 
[FIRST|AFTER col_name]
```

For this example:

```sql
ALTER TABLE xyz CHANGE manufacurerid manufacturerid datatype(length)
```

**Reference:**   [MYSQL 5.1 ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 42):

FOR MYSQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `old_name` `new_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

FOR ORACLE:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` RENAME COLUMN `old_name` TO `new_name`;
```

Comment: It doesn't work if you use `"` for the column names for MySQL. Use nothing or ` instead.

Answer (score 14):

#### EDIT

You can rename fields using:

```
ALTER TABLE xyz CHANGE manufacurerid manufacturerid INT
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: This would be useful, but it's not true to the documentation you cited: "When you use CHANGE or MODIFY, **column_definition must include the data type and all attributes that should apply to the new column** [...] Attributes present in the original definition but not specified for the new definition are not carried forward. "

Comment: it has to be "ALTER TABLE xyz CHANGE manufacurerid manufacturerid datatype(length)"

Answer (score 7):

There is a syntax problem, because the right syntax to alter command is `ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE OldColumnName NewColunmName DATATYPE;`

Answer (score 2):

With MySQL 5.x you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
CHANGE COLUMN old_column_name new_column_name DATATYPE NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Renaming a column in MySQL :**

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE current_column_name new_column_name DATATYPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

> ALTER TABLE  CHANGE   ;

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE global_user CHANGE deviceToken deviceId VARCHAR(255) ;
```

Answer (score -5):

SYNTAX

alter table **table_name** rename column **old column name** to **new column name**;

*Example:*

alter table **library** rename column **cost** to **price**;

Comment: In mysql RENAME is used for renaming table not a column ,to rename a column use CHANGE.

Comment: Question is for MySQL - this isn't valid syntax in MySQL.

Comment: As others note, please use valid MySQL syntax.

Comment: There is invalid mysql syntax.