# MySQL: having trouble with rename of auto_incriment column

Tags: mysql

On some versions of mysql (e.g. `5.0.77, for Win32 (ia32)`) I'm having trouble with the following query

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `old` `new` integer auto_increment
```

I'm getting `Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

How that can be ommited?

Comment: Possible duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002340/how-to-rename-a-table-column-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

If the column is *already* an auto-increment primary key, just change its name and supply the data type. (MySQL will error if the data type isn't supplied here). The existing auto-increment and key definition will be retained.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `old` `new` INT
```

If you are changing its name and making an auto-increment where there previously wasn't one, you need to specify the index or make it a primary key in the same statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `old` `new` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Note however, that if you have *another* column on this table already serving as `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then the error as reported is correct and you will not be able to specify a second `AUTO_INCREMENT` column. You have to choose one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first disable auto-increment, then make the changes, then turn it back auto_increment.
Try this (this will change it to INT):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY COLUMN `old` INT;
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE COLUMN `old` `new` integer
ALTER TABLE `table_name` MODIFY COLUMN `new` INT AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Answer (score 1):

***try this one:***

```
  ALTER TABLE `t1` CHANGE COLUMN `uid` `id` INT  AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

***Another one interesting answer:***

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN 'old_id','new_id' INT auto_increment;
```

[click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169090/3242978)