# I can't alter table in mysql

Tags: mysql, rename

Im trying to rename a column in one of my tables but MySQL returns me this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN IPorigen TO IPorig' at line 1
```

This is the statement I tried using to rename the column:

```
ALTER TABLE InformeGeneral RENAME COLUMN IPorigen TO IPorig;
```

I have also tried this too:

```
sp_RENAME 'InformeGeneral.IPorigen' , 'IPorig' , 'COLUMN';
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong?
My MySQL version is: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2`

Comment: Sorry for repeat the question, I'm new here and english isn't my language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax to rename your column:

```
ALTER TABLE InformeGeneral CHANGE IPorigen IPorig datatype(length)
```

Replace datatype with `INT, VARCHAR` or whatever you need for that column.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a valid statement It should be as

```
alter table table_name change col_name new_col_name datatype
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html

SO  in your case it should be as

```
ALTER TABLE InformeGeneral change IPorigen IPorig;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this. 
[Error renaming a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002340/how-to-rename-a-table-column-in-mysql)

Probaly you need to add the datatype of your column

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( Assuming type of `IPorigen` is varchar ):

```
ALTER TABLE InformeGeneral change COLUMN IPorigen  IPorig varchar(30);
```