# Changing column name with Constraints connected to it (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I have a table 
`car` 
carID 
name

and another table 
`wheel` 
carID 
name

Trying to change the column `car`.carID to ID, 
I get `Error on rename of...` 
Due to the Constraints of the wheel table,  
how can I still rename the column? 
(my DB is far more complex than this example, so manually is a no go)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can this be the option,

```
first delete all constraints associated with the column

change column name

again apply all the constraints
```

[Renaming foreign-key columns in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014498/renaming-foreign-key-columns-in-mysql)