# MySQL - How I can rename a column?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

So far I am doing it this way:

```
"ALTER TABLE `database_name`.`table_name` CHANGE 
`old_column_name` `new_column_name` column_type_now"
```

But this is problematic if the column had not NULL default values or was a key since those things are discarded when the column is renamed.

How I can deal with this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming foreign-key columns in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014498/renaming-foreign-key-columns-in-mysql)

Comment: Why is this question tagged with vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
ALTER TABLE `database_name`.`table_name` CHANGE 
`old_column_name` `NEW Column Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NOT NULL
```

Replace Varchar with the type of column you're making.

You can also just make it

```
`DEFAULT NULL`
```

If you prefer it to be null.

Did that work?

Comment: Oh im sorry. The only thing I would know other than that would be to just make a new table and import the data but that is time consuming. and not very scalable.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name" CHANGE "old_column_name" "new_column_name" DATATYPE;

FOR ORACLE:

ALTER TABLE "table_name" RENAME COLUMN "old_column_name" TO "new_column_name";
```