# how to modify the foreign key column name and how to drop foreign key in Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

how to modify the foreign key column name and how to drop foreign key in **Mysql**   when we drop than **Error 150** comes and when modify or rename than **error 152 comes**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming foreign-key columns in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014498/renaming-foreign-key-columns-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

while trying to drop a foreign key, use the constraint name rather than the column name of the foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` DROP FOREIGN KEY `id_name_fk`
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE `thetable`
  DROP KEY `oldkey`, 
  ADD KEY `newkey` (`tablefield`);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
DROP FOREIGN KEY 'table_name_consraint',
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_table_name_consraint` FOREIGN KEY (`column`) REFERENCES `table_name` (`column`);
```