# unable to drop the foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, mysql-error-1025

I would like to drop the foreign key in my table but been into this error message

```
mysql> alter table customers drop foreign key customerid;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of '.\products\customers' to '.\products\#sql2-7ec-a3' (errno: 152)
mysql>
```

Comment: This may help you to understand 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-me

Comment: @Imdad This link describes another error - (errno: 150)

Comment: Try this. Create new table (without foreign key constraint). copy the data to new table (using syntax INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM old_table)  Drop the old table

Comment: Have you checked @Maksym Polshcha's answer? You have to use the foreign key's name not the column name. (it might be something like fk_customerid)

Comment: check my answer and let me know if you still have problem...

Comment: I also got this error when trying to use `DROP FOREIGN KEY` on a key that wasn't actually foreign - changing to `DROP KEY` fixed my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid getting this error while trying to drop a foreign key, use the constraint name rather than the column name of the foreign key.

When I tried

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

I got error as

```
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of '.\database\#sql-454_3' to '.\database\mytable' (errno: 150).
```

I solved it using:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE mytable DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY (column1,column2,column3);
```

Some links that will help you.

[link 1](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/08/22/mysqls-error-1025-explained/)

[link 2](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-error-codes.html) [look for Posted by Alex Blume on November 7 2008 5:09pm & Posted by Hector Delgadillo on January 21 2011 4:57am]

Answer (score 35):

The solution described [here by Chris White](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/204199) worked for me.

The root problem is that MySQL creates both an index and a foreign key. Both must be removed (the foreign key first contrary to what Chris said).

1. show create table table_name;

   ```
   SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`:

   | table_name | CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
     `id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
     `key_column` smallint(5) unsigned default '1',
     KEY `column_tablein_26440ee6` (`key_column`),  <--- shows key name
     CONSTRAINT `table_name_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`key_column`) REFERENCES <--- shows foreign key constraint name
   `second_table` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
   ```
2. Delete the foreign key constraint:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE table_name DROP FOREIGN KEY `table_name_ibfk_1`;
   ```
3. Delete the key

   ```
   ALTER TABLE table_name DROP KEY `column_tablein_26440ee6`;
   ```

That did it for me.

Comment: +1 Want to add that there's many questions (perhaps duplicates) of this, and the answer by @bbrame is the one that worked for me.

Comment: i dont have constraint section in show create table 'name' but when i do desc 'name' i can see field to have foreign key constraint

Comment: This is a perfect example which shows how to deal with foreign key drop. Many many thanks to @bbframe .it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like a bug in the error messaging of MySQL. (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10333)

Use SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name` to see the *actual name* of the foreign key. It looks like it might be mysql query browser problem when generating the query with wrong spelling of the foreign key name.

Comment: It helps me to know that my constraint was created as INDEX, not FOREIGN KEY. Then I used "DROP INDEX" clause. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid getting this error while trying to drop a foreign key, use the constraint name rather than the column name of the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You should try with the foreign key name as Fahim Parkar suggested. Actually that does not work always either.

In my case I used the

```
FOREIGN KEY `fk`(`col1`) REFERENCES `table2`(`col1`)
```

code to add the fk by creation.

The problem with this code that it is not valid and should throw some kind of syntax error, but still it added a foreign key with a random name.

When I added the fk with the right syntax:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`col1`) REFERENCES `table2`(`col1`)
```

the following code dropped it properly:

```
ALTER TABLE `table1` DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk`
```

So this kind of error can happen too if you try to remove a foreign key with an invalid name. It is important to view the table properties with

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table1`
```

and check the foreign key names if you get this kind of errors.