# MySQL dropped all indexes on conversion from InnoDB to MyISAM, errors out when trying to switch back

Tags: mysql

I don't know why, what, how or who could make changes to all my databases.. I have a hosting account where all my databases tables changed from InnoDB to MyISAM and all my indexes has been lost. All my relational data has been lost also.

Why could happend this? (I've just contacted the hosting company and they told me that they didn't made any changes on any database and the problem could be from a programmer of my company.. Now.. the problem is that I'm the only programmer who have accessed these accounts and I really know what I've did.. so they just pass the problem to me without any explanation)

Now I'm trying to change the tables back and to recreate the indexes and relational data.. The problem is that on some of them I have an error when I'm trying to change the type of the table from MyISAM to InnoDB.

I've tried to rename it from phpmyadmin and also with sql query

`ALTER TABLE categories ENGINE = INNODB`

This returns me this error. Why?

`#1025 - Error on rename of './database_name/#sql-6ad0_146c29' to './database_name/categories' (errno: 121)`

Comment: Don't you (or your hosting) have a backup of your database? No logs to check neither?

Comment: Sounds like it won't let you due to foreign key constraints or something. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-me)

Comment: Can you include a 'show create table' ?