# Upgrade magento from 1.3 to 1.4 then to 1.8 but getting loop of array on homepage

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.8, mage

ive updated a site from 1.3 to 1.4 as suggested via docs, and then done to 1.9 latest but now when i hit the homepage it just keeps constantly reloading and showing:

Any ideas on how i can sort this, ive spent ages looking online but to me seems like the updating did not update the database maybe??

Thanks in advance

```
PDOException Object
(
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of './seedpant_staging/#sql-351f_1680c1' to './seedpant_staging/core_layout_link' (errno: 150)
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => HY000
    [file:protected] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
    [line:protected] => 228
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
                    [line] => 228
                    [function] => execute
                    [class] => PDOStatement
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 110
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php
                    [line] => 291
                    [function] => _execute
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php
                    [line] => 480
                    [function] => execute
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Statement
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php
                    [line] => 238
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ALTER TABLE `core_layout_link` DROP KEY `store_id`
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 428
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ALTER TABLE `core_layout_link` DROP KEY `store_id`
                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 347
                    [function] => query
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ALTER TABLE `core_layout_link` DROP KEY `store_id`
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
                    [line] => 2686
                    [function] => raw_query
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ALTER TABLE `core_layout_link` DROP KEY `store_id`
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php
                    [line] => 163
                    [function] => dropIndex
                    [class] => Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => core_layout_link
                            [1] => STORE_ID
                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 624
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php
                        )

                    [function] => include
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 437
                    [function] => _modifyResourceDb
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => upgrade
                            [1] => 0.8.28
                            [2] => 1.6.0.4
                        )

                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 320
                    [function] => _upgradeResourceDb
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0.8.28
                            [1] => 1.6.0.4
                        )

                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
                    [line] => 235
                    [function] => applyUpdates
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                    [line] => 417
                    [function] => applyAllUpdates
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php
                    [line] => 343
                    [function] => _initModules
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/app/Mage.php
                    [line] => 684
                    [function] => run
                    [class] => Mage_Core_Model_App
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [scope_code] => 
                                    [scope_type] => store
                                    [options] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /home/seedpant/public_html/staging/index.php
                    [line] => 87
                    [function] => run
                    [class] => Mage
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => store
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [errorInfo] => Array
        (
            [0] => HY000
            [1] => 1025
            [2] => Error on rename of './seedpant_staging/#sql-351f_1680c1' to './seedpant_staging/core_layout_link' (errno: 150)
        )

)
```

Comment: something's doing an alter table, and failing.

Comment: i assume so yea, its upgrading from a few versions so i assume needs to alter a few tables but its not.... and thats all i get - looking at the local.xml on server side the mysql details are all correct so im a little lost

Comment: looking at it, i cannot see any failure error or reasons why though, would be nice if it said why it was failing haha

Comment: the dump gives the alter: it's trying to drop a key. that means rebuild the entire table in a temp file, then rename the tempfile to the original name when complete. something's prevent that rename from occuring. check disk space, check permissions, etc...etc...etc..

Comment: Disk space is not the issue, account has allocated space of 10gb and only using 2gb plus i own the server and managed all accounts and just checked so thats not the issue. Do you know what permissions i would need to be checking here? and whats etc.. etc.. etc.. sorry this is a new clients site we have taken over and im not a magento guy so its trial and error for me. Appreciate your help mate

Comment: Interesting... i just tried to manually execute "ALTER TABLE `core_layout_link` DROP KEY `store_id`" in phpmyadmin and got back " #1025 - Error on rename of './seedpant_staging/#sql-351f_168574' to './seedpant_staging/core_layout_link' (errno: 150) "

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-me

Comment: yea i was looking at that already and i get "InnoDB   
=====================================
140522 21:4..." but not sure now what i do with that data??

Comment: "show engine status innodb" will have a section with "last foreign key error". it should say what the FK is, and where.

Comment: All it shows is "Type: InnoDB | Name: BLANK | Status: =====================================
140522 21:4..."

Comment: after doing a little bit of reading seems magento 1.3 does not use the innodb engine and needs to be converted so just trying to work that out :)