# MySQL change collation error

Tags: mysql, collation

I try to change collation on MySQL table from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8_general_ci`. I used query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
MODIFY myfield varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`
```

But this query result `errno 150`. I think this is because foreign key that reference into mytable. I try to delete all record on my database, I drop all foreign keys also. I try to run again. But still result `errno 150`.

Any idea about my problem ?

Comment: Do you have an error message in addition to the error code 150 ? Run again your `ALTER TABLE`, and once you have the error, run the command `show errors;`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does mysql error 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './foo' (errorno: 150) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-me)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a COLLATION related error but a Foreign Key one.

> Altering a table returns an error (errno: 150) if a foreign key definition is incorrectly formed for the altered table.
> [Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#:%7E:text=Altering%20a%20table%20returns%20an,formed%20for%20the%20altered%20table.)

Comment: If the paragraph you have formatted as a block quote is actually quoting something, then you should provide a link to the source.