# Rename column name of a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rename

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'sp_rename 'records.student_id', 'id', 'COLUMN'' at
>   line 1.

Help to resolve this error.

```
mysql> sp_rename 'records.student_id', 'id', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: this is sql-server syntax. not mysql. Read about [alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: mysql or sql-server ????

Comment: @Jens:does the above code is wrong??...i came across this code in the internet , to rename the column.

Comment: @deka4tech It is wrong for mysql, because it is for SQL-Server from microsoft!

Comment: @Jens: ALTER TABLE is not working..the one u prescribed..throwing following error-mysql> ALTER TABLE records CHANGE 'student_id' 'id' INT Not NULL; ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''student_id' 'id' INT Not NULL' at line 1 –

Comment: @deka4tech remove the single quotes arround column names: ALTER TABLE records CHANGE student_id id INT Not NULL

Comment: @Jens:mysql> ALTER TABLE records CHANGE student_id id INT NOT NULL;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './test/#sql-49c_34' to './test/records' (errno: 150)

Comment: @deka4tech Looks like you have an index on that table drop it before and recreate it after renaming

Comment: @Jens: The student_id column is defined as primary key...can it be a reason for the error???

Comment: @deka4tech i do not think so

Comment: @Jens: what u said about the index thing on the table(dropping it)..I didnt understand...what is that??

Comment: @deka4tech You should learn about the basics before using a db

Comment: @Jens: can u provide some link to learn that index stuff..it would be great help

Comment: @deka4tech You will find some in the official mysql doku

Comment: @deka4tech Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-me

Comment: @Jens:thnnx man

Answer (score 3):

Try like this. Without quotes.

```
ALTER TABLE records CHANGE student_id id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: student_id is declared as primary key...can it causing the problem..has something more to be added in the query after the NOT NULL in the end????

Comment: You should remove the blanks inside the backticks

Comment: mysql> ALTER TABLE `records` CHANGE `student_id` `id` INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './test/#sql-49c_34' to './test/records' (errno: 150)

Answer (score 1):

sp_rename  is for SQL Server. Use ALTER TABLE for MYSQL

```
 ALTER TABLE `records` CHANGE `student_id` `id` INT NOT NULL;
```

For SQL Server

```
EXEC sp_rename 'records.student_id', 'id', 'COLUMN'
```

Comment: :its not working..throwing following error-mysql> ALTER TABLE records CHANGE 'student_id' 'id' INT Not NULL;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''student_id' 'id' INT Not NULL' at line 1

Comment: @deka4tech I think u used quote instead of backticks around column names

Comment: mysql> ALTER TABLE `records` CHANGE `student_id` `id` `COLUMN` INT NOT NULL;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`COLUMN` INT NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: student_id is defined as primary key..can it be a reason for the error??

Comment: You arent executing the same query. Where did COLUMN came from in ALTER TABLE?

Comment: mysql> ALTER TABLE records CHANGE student_id id int NOT NULL;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './test/#sql-49c_34' to './test/records' (errno: 150)

Comment: @deka4tech the link jens provided will help

Comment: @deka4tech Is it have something to do with foreign keys