# Changing referenced primary key

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a primary key. I want to add a new column and make that one the primary key. However, I can't drop the primary key constraint on the old column, because it is referenced as a foreign key in another table.
So I dropped the foreign key constraint and the index:

```
ALTER TABLE experiments DROP FOREIGN KEY experiments_ibfk_1
ALTER TABLE experiments DROP INDEX `analysisfk`;
```

I checked with `show create` that both constraint and index are gone. Then I tried to drop the primary key again with

```
ALTER TABLE analysis DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

However, I still got an Error 1025. 
Am I overlooking something?

**SOLVED:** There was another key constraint which I overlooked because of a misleading name. Leaving this here anyway as it shows some useful stuff

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160233/what-does-mysql-error-1025-hy000-error-on-rename-of-foo-errorno-150-me

Comment: @tuckbloor not really, I used `drop foreign key` as well, I didn't drop the column but that's because I want to keep it

Comment: Just tried it myself and works as expected the PK is gone. Now you can create a new one.

Comment: @TheImpaler yeah but that is exactly the problem, if I try dropping the primary key with the above command, I get an error

Comment: Show us the DDL for all tables involve. So we can tell you wich order you need to drop Keys and Index.