# Getting Django - MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1025, 'Error on rename of )

Tags: django, mariadb

I am trying to connect my Django project to mariaDB but I am getting error

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1025, 'Error on rename of \'./mydb/auth_permission\' to \'./mydb/#sql-backup-13c39-4a\' (errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")')
```

I tried removing the foreign keys and dropping the table but it still does not work. Tried this solution as well https://confluence.atlassian.com/confkb/mysql-error-1025-thrown-when-attempting-to-change-table-collation-and-character-set-785332187.html
but had no effect at all.

Comment: You have to find the name of the index. You can't drop the FK by column name. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5615783/1421112

Comment: I dont think I can run the 'alter table' command because everything is default for django. The error that is in the question occurs while migrating.